# I'm using a java application to parse some XML using XStream

Tags: java, xml, xstream

This is the Method Java

```
 public static void ImportarXMLDepartamentos() throws FileNotFoundException {

    xstream = new XStream();
    xstream.setClassLoader(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader());

    xstream.alias("ListaDepartamentos", ListaDepartamentos.class);
    xstream.alias("Departamento", ListaDepartamentos.Departamento.class);
    xstream.addImplicitCollection(ListaDepartamentos.class, "departamento");
    xstream.addPermission(AnyTypePermission.ANY);

    ListaDepartamentos listado = (ListaDepartamentos) xstream.fromXML(new FileInputStream("copia.xml"));

    List<ListaDepartamentos.Departamento> listadoDepartamentos = new ArrayList<ListaDepartamentos.Departamento>();
    listadoDepartamentos = listado.getDepartamento();

    Iterator iterador = listadoDepartamentos.listIterator();
    while (iterador.hasNext()) {
        Departamento dep = (Departamento) iterador.next();
        System.out.println(dep.getDeptNo());

    }
    System.out.println("Fin");
}
```

This is the XML

```
<antes>

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    
    -<ListaDepartamentos>
    
    
    -<Departamento>
    
    <Dept_no>10</Dept_no>
    
    <Nombre>Programacion</Nombre>
    
    <Localizacion>Madrid</Localizacion>
    
    </Departamento>
    
    
    -<Departamento>
    
    <Dept_no>20</Dept_no>
    
    <Nombre>Disenio</Nombre>
    
    <Localizacion>Albacete</Localizacion>
    
    </Departamento>
    
    
    -<Departamento>
    
    <Dept_no>30</Dept_no>
    
    <Nombre>Programacion</Nombre>
    
    <Localizacion>Madrid</Localizacion>
    
    </Departamento>
    
    </ListaDepartamentos>
</pre>
```

[Edit note: I included everything above that looked like XML, however the OP my not have intended all of this to be the actual XML source.  Caveat emptor.]

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: I need to solve java.lang.ClassCastException 
and I don't know how to do it

Comment: You might want to include some information about the error then.

Comment: this is the error in question Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to generated.ListaDepartamentos

Comment: `A ClassCastException [occurs] if, after the type conversions above have been applied, the resulting value is an object which is not an instance of a subclass or subinterface of the erasure (§4.6) of the type of the variable.`  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.2

Comment: thanks for your help good man, you helped me.